# second module not working in HMVC in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, hmvc

I am using HMVC in codeigniter
This is my file structure .

[image]

When i am accessing by

```
http://localhost/mysite/adminw/login
```

Than it is working fine but same as when i am calling

```
http://localhost/mysite/member-area/login
```

it will throw **404**

Answer (score 1):

**Solves the issue.!**

Codeigniter HMVC does not support "-" *(Dash)*

So i change my folder name with **member-area** to **member** and it start working

Rules foe naming in HMVC

1. Folder name does not contain any special character
2. Folder name does not contain space

Answer (score 0):

Please check your codeigniter config file where dash is allow in url or not.